# Silverlight + Sharepoint ClientContext. How to set multilookup field?

Tags: .net, silverlight, sharepoint, client

I have example how to work with sharepoint data from silverlight client:

```
 var tipSenderList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List title");
                    tipItem = tipSenderList.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
         contactItem["FirstName"] = model.Name;
```

All data stored to sharepoint portal without problems... 
But how can i store multilookup field?
I tried:

```
 contactItem["Contacts"] = "1,2,3";
```

But was stored only first.... What can i do to save multilookup field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution.

delimiter is ;#

```
contactItem["Contacts"] = "1;#'';#2;#'';#3;#''";
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just as well use

```
contactItem["Contacts"] = ";#1;#;#2;#;#3;#";
```

SharePoint parses this correctly as well. It might allow easier formatting...